# Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((err: any) => void)

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface in typescript

```
interface ConfigOptions {
    autoloadCallback: (err: any) => void;
}
```

in my implementation I have

```
options = {
  autoloadCallback: this.autoLoadCallBack(err)
}

public autoLoadCallBack(err: any) : void {
  console.log('im a callback');
};
```

which throws the following error

> Types of property 'autoloadCallback' are incompatible.
>   Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((err: any) => void) | undefined'.

since autoLoadCallBack takes any type and doesn't return anything should it match the interface specification?

Comment: `options.autoloadCallback` is supposed to be a function, right?  But you've set it to the `void` return value of a function.   And the error is telling you that.  Why not `options = {autoloadCallback: this.autoLoadCallback.bind(this)}` or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `this.autoLoadCallBack` then assigning the return value of that function (which in this case is nothing, as it's void) to `options.autoloadCallback`.

You seem to be trying to assigning the `this.autoLoadCallBack` function to `options.autoloadCallback` directly, which would look like this:

```
options = {
  autoloadCallback: this.autoLoadCallBack
}

public autoLoadCallBack(err: any) : void {
  console.log('im a callback');
};
```

Comment: so why does adding parameters to this.autoLoadCallBack cause this to fail?

Comment: @user618509: `this.autoLoadCallBack(err)` *calls* the function, `this.autoLoadCallBack` *is* the function. If you want a more practical example, examine the difference between running `console.log` and `console.log("hello, world")` in your browser's console.